# Data Access Object class getting SQLServerException

Tags: java, singleton, database-connection, factory, dao

I'm getting the following execption when executing sql statements

> SQLServerException: The server failed to resume the transaction.
>   Desc:69d00000016.

I know that the following DAO implementation is not correct. I want to know what is the correct implementation for the following code and if the fact that my connFactory is declared as static can cause the above error.

```
private static DbConnectionFactory connFactory;

    protected myDAO() {
        myDAO.connFactory = DbConnectionFactoryHome.getHome().lookupFactory("facName");
    }

    public myReturn myAccessMethod(final int cod) throws BaseException {
        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement stmt = null;
        ResultSet resSet = null;
        myReturn ret= null;

        try {
            conn = myDAO.connFactory.getConnection();
            stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call name (2)}");
            stmt.setInt(1, cod);
            resSet = stmt.executeQuery();
            if (resSet.next()) {                    
                ret = new myReturn(resSet.getInt("someValue"));                    
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException sqle) {                
            throw new myException(sqle.getMessage(), (Throwable)sqle);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (resSet != null) {
                    resSet.close();
                }
                if (stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            }                
        }            
        return ret;
    }
```

Should I remove the static modifier from the connFactory or implement a singleton, so when the constructor is called again the factory is not recreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make your DBConnectionFactory a singleton. A good example of how to do this can be found here: [Singleton DB Connectionfactory.](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java/jdbc/jdbc-examples-introduction/#Singleton_design_pattern)

However, I am not sure that the your issue is with the db connection factory being static. It may actually be with the way you are extracting results with the result set. Make sure you process all your results. **You should include a more complete stack trace.** You may want to look into why you are getting: "*The server failed to resume the transaction*." There is an article about how what causes this error and how to fix it here: [Failed to resume transaction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2009/02/24/the-server-failed-to-resume-the-transaction-why/)

Try doing something like this:

```
CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("{call name (2)}");
stmt.setInt(1, cod);

stmt.execute();

ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)stmt.getObject(index);

//Loop results
while (rs.next()) {
  ret = new myReturn(resSet.getInt("someValue")
}
```

Comment: I understood that I need to process all the results before calling another statement in the same connection, but in this case only one statement can be called in the same connection.

Comment: Can you post more of your stack trace when you get the error?